# Error : Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I am trying to show cache size files in MB, used by my App. but my app crashing. Error : Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException

```
private void initializeCache() {
    long size = 0;
    size += getDirSize(this.getCacheDir());
    size += getDirSize(this.getExternalCacheDir());
    this.text_view_cache_value.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.label_cache)  + readableFileSize(size));

}

public long getDirSize(File dir){
    long size = 0;
    for (File file : dir.listFiles()) {
        if (file != null && file.isDirectory()) {
            size += getDirSize(file);
        } else if (file != null && file.isFile()) {
            size += file.length();
        }
    }
    return size;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Set a debug point or do a *System.out.println(..)* to check the content of :

```
this.getCacheDir()
his.getExternalCacheDir()
this.text_view_cache_value
R.string.label_cache
```

one of them has a null value.

Comment: That is really more of a comment. Surprising, that somebody upvoted it.

Comment: Sorry, at the time I wrote it, I did not had enough reputation points to write a comment but only a response. I think that one of those variables is null and that my response is accurate provided the information the opener of the post, a beginner, gave. What the trouble about helping him ?